# CSS | Ordered list in single vertical column above list item

Tags: html, css, html-lists

i'm looking to create an ordered list (decimal) in which all the items are rag-left aligned with their numerical header. for example:

> > List
> >
> > 1.
> >
> > This is list item 1
> >
> > 2.
> >
> > This is list item 2
> >
> > 3.
> >
> > This is list item 3

I've been looking around but haven't found any way of implementing this. I still would like to use an  since it scales better than manually entering numbers. Is there anyway to treat and  list as a single col?

Comment: kindly provide fiddle link it will be easy to answer your question

Comment: Look at [this DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/z4gafdp7/). Is that good enough for you?

Comment: @Crabolo, i usually include code snippets but in this case i couldn't remotely get it to function as intended, so i hoped a "diagram" would suffice. the included code at most would have been an <ol> list with padding and margins reset (not very helpful).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @Imgonzalves pointed out ---

HTML

```
<ol>
    <li><span>list item</span></li>
    <li><span>list item</span></li>
    <li><span>list item</span></li>
</ol>
```

CSS

```
ol li span {
    position: relative;
    left: -20px;
    display:block;
}
```

including his pen here: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/z4gafdp7/

Answer (score 2):

Behold, CSS counters!  I put comments in the CSS explaining the solution.  [This article by Louis Lazaris](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-css-counters-and-their-use-cases/) does an excellent job of explaining the details.

```css
.fancy-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none; /* hide original list numbering */
  counter-reset: ordered-list; /* initialize CSS counter */
}
.fancy-list li {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.fancy-list li::before {
  display: block; /* display numbering as block to force content down */
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  counter-increment: ordered-list; /* increment CSS counter for every <li> in the list */
  content: counter(ordered-list) "."; /* output counter value and append a "." */
}
```

```html
<p>This solution has the following benefits:</p>
<ol class="fancy-list">
  <li>does not require superfluous HTML</li>
  <li>maintains semantics of an ordered list</li>
  <li>is flexible; doesn't matter how many items you have</li>
  <li>you don't need to adjust the left margin for list items if you change the list's left margin</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty block element before every `li` element, that way you can achieve the effect `li` content to be on new line without having to type `<br/>` at the beginning of every list item.

```css
li{
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
li:before { content: ' '; display: block; }
```

```html
<ol> 
    <li> list item </li>
    <li> list item </li>
    <li> list item </li>
    <li> list item </li>
</ol>
```

You can create an emtpy block element before every `li` element, that way you can achieve the effect to be on new line.

Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h423hdn4/)

Comment: this renders with 2 cols: one for <ol> one for <li>. i'm looking for a single col solution.